# can contenteditable be set in css files?

Tags: html, css

very simply I want to set the contenteditable property.
why is the p elements not editable?

```css
p{contenteditable:true;}
```

```html
<p>not editable</p>

<div contenteditable="true">this is </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can contenteditable be set in css files?

No. It isn't a presentational feature so is out of scope for what CSS tries to achieve.

Comment: this seems to be wrong as this does something in that regard: 



   css

    .myDiv:hover > *[contenteditable="true"] {
      background-color: rgba(217, 245, 255,0.5);
    }

Comment: @Nivatius — Writing a selector that styles contenteditable elements is completely different to using CSS to *make* an element contenteditable.

Comment: all right, that makes sense. so to achieve this I should javascript then.